# datatables: style becomes bold when inserting a piece of data

Tags: datatables

Set datatables through ajax way every few seconds to automatically refresh from the database to read data, when the empty table to join a data table style becomes particularly thick, f5 after the style can return to normal.

Automatic refresh datatables code:

```
function autoRefresh() {
$('#demo').DataTable().draw(false);
t = setTimeout('autoRefresh()', 5 * 1000);
}
```

This code I have tried the same problem:

```
setInterval( function () {
table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
}, 5 * 1000 );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are drawing a new table on top of the previous table with the new dataset. In the documentation, where it explains the ajax.reload() function, the example is table is being initialized differently. Assuming that you are loading data in via a JSON object, I would suggest doing it that way rather than redrawing the table..

```
var table = $('#demo').DataTable({
    ajax: "data.json"
});

setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
}, 30000 );
```

Comment: I'm sorry to have bothered you again, and a new problem arose. What if I want the datatables table to automatically refresh to reload the data, but I do not want the data in one of the columns to be reloaded?If I use this code will appear above the problem of style thicker`table.search('status').draw(false);`

Comment: Or in fact my purpose is to datatables this form can be automatically loaded on a column to update the data, while the other column data remain unchanged, of course, if used`draw()`, there will be style problems